# Wicket Custom Pagination

Tags: pagination, wicket

i have been trying to trying to implement something like

<< <  (textbox)  of (totalnumberofpages) > >>

any suggestions on this

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please explain more what you are trying to do and provide some cod you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for pagination in DataView then ,all you need to do to enable paging is to call setItemsPerPage(int) on the dataview.

Check following example  **JAVA** code

```
    public class RepeatingPage extends BasePage
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public RepeatingPage()
    {
        Iterator<Contact> contacts = new ContactDataProvider().iterator(0, 10);

        RepeatingView repeating = new RepeatingView("repeating");
        add(repeating);

        int index = 0;
        while (contacts.hasNext())
        {
            AbstractItem item = new AbstractItem(repeating.newChildId());

            repeating.add(item);
            Contact contact = contacts.next();

            item.add(new ActionPanel("actions", new DetachableContactModel(contact)));
            item.add(new Label("contactid", String.valueOf(contact.getId())));
            item.add(new Label("firstname", contact.getFirstName()));
            item.add(new Label("lastname", contact.getLastName()));
            item.add(new Label("homephone", contact.getHomePhone()));
            item.add(new Label("cellphone", contact.getCellPhone()));

            final int idx = index;
            item.add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>()
            {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public String getObject()
                {
                    return (idx % 2 == 1) ? "even" : "odd";
                }
            }));

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML** code

```
<wicket:extend xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<br/><br/>

<table cellspacing="0" class="dataview">
    <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Home Phone</th>
        <th>Cell Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr wicket:id="repeating">
        <td><span wicket:id="actions">[actions]</span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="contactid">[contactid]</span> </td>
        <td><span wicket:id="firstname">[firstname]</span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="lastname">[lastname]</span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="homephone">[homephone]</span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="cellphone">[cellphone]</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</wicket:extend>
```

If you need pagination in listView then check for [PageableListView](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/PageableListView.html)