# I would like to implement pagination in Wicket

Tags: wicket

Can someone provide the way to implement paging like  `<< 1 2 3 ... 11 12 13 >>` where 13 will be the last page.

I also tried with PagingNavigation and PagingNavigator but both provides different kind of paging.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you referenced [this example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.DataTablePage?2), for instance, and are there specific issues you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wicket Custom Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451220/wicket-custom-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom component to do this. Looking at the source code of `PagingNavigation` and `PagingNavigator` should give you a few hints.

Your requirement is not entirly clear as well. For example, what should your paging look like when, say, page 5 is the active page? Of page 50 out of 100?

You will need to decide what to build. You will probably need two [Repeaters](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/) (for example `Loop`s) to build the begin and end series, and maybe a `Loop` to display the pages around the currently-selected page.

Comment: When we hit ">>" , it should move us to next page. Irrespective of how many pages are there the last page link should be visible. If the page 5 is active page then  << 1 .. 4 5 6 .. 13 >>